# almost sure convergence of expected value

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X:\Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}= \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty \}$ a random variable.

If $\mathbb{E}[|X|]=0,$ how can I show that $X=0$ almost sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Markov's inequality, $\mathbb P(|X| > \varepsilon) \le \mathbb{E}[|X|]/\varepsilon = 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.  Therefore $|X| \le \varepsilon$ a.s. for all $\varepsilon > 0$ and therefore $|X| = 0$ a.s.

Comment: How you concluded that $|X|\leq \epsilon$? @user6247850

Comment: We have $\mathbb P(|X| \le \varepsilon) = 1-\mathbb P(|X| > \varepsilon) = 1$

Comment: I have a question: I understand your calculations but how this implies that $|X|=0$ almost sure?